# Trying to convert a list with multiple meanings

Tags: bash

I am trying to convert a list into another using a conversion list, but the conversion list has multiple meanings and I am unsure how to approach this. For example I have this list with only numbers:

```
1 4  
2 5  
3 6  
5 1
```

I have this second list with conversions (1 --> apple, etc):

```
1 apple  
2 blueberry  
2 banana  
3 orange  
4 pear  
5 cherry  
6 kiwi  
6 mango
```

Using this 2nd list of conversions, I want to change the list of numbers to a list of fruits. This is my desired output:

```
apple pear  
blueberry cherry  
banana cherry  
orange kiwi  
orange mango  
cherry apple
```

Since "2" has both blueberry and banana, I would see two lines instead of the original one. Is this conversion possible with bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read index fruit
do
    data[$index]="${data[index]} $fruit"
done < fruit.txt

while read one two
do
    for fruit1 in ${data[$one]}
    do
        for fruit2 in ${data[$two]}
        do
            echo $fruit1 $fruit2
        done
    done
done < list.txt
```

This works as follows: First, read the file containing conversions (`fruit.txt`) into the array `data`. Next, read the file containing two columns of numbers (`list.txt`) and use the numbers to look up the fruit in the array `data`. Since each entry might contain more than one type of fruit, iterate over all entries.

Comment: Would you be able to explain your code a bit? I'm not sure I quite understand.